# On a request having a function which will only run after 30 min in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a Web API that uses .NET Framework and Nancyfx.

On some specific endpoint I want to start a function that will execute after 30min, and I don't want the rest to be waiting for it.

I want this function to be fire and forget (and then it executes after 30min).

Maybe I can do something like this

```
private async Task LogExceptionsAsync(Func<Task> code)
{
  try
  {
    await code();
  }
  catch(Exception exception)
  {
    m_log.Error("Call failed: " + exception.ToString());
  }
}
```

```
int id = 1 //id of table
BackgroundTaskManager.Run(() => LogExceptionsAsync(() => DoUpdateOnTableAsync(id)));
```

But is this a good approach?

What if the website has many requests putting a load on it? What should be my concerns?

Comment: since it would be a web api, you might split this into 3 parts, 
1) The trigger which stores the Request somewhere (REDIS/DB ect)
2) A service which checks the if there are tasks to be executed 
3) The execution of your task

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is your application data is not persistent.

If your application crash for any reason the job will not run.

You can use **job** libraries like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) that can schedule jobs and support persistency via SQL server or other DB's.

An example of delayed job enqueuing:

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Delayed!"),
    TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
```